# Printing result of re.search in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and struggling for a simple code.
I have a string like :

```
ERROR_CODE=0,ERROR_MSG=null,SESSION_ID=2a50250f-4a2e-4bf9-b1a7-7a8030333de2|||33a3b23d-2143
```

I want to get the `SESSION_ID=2a50250f-4a2e-4bf9-b1a7-7a8030333de2` from the string using re.search().

My Code:

```
line=ERROR_CODE=0,ERROR_MSG=null,SESSION_ID=2a50250f-4a2e-4bf9-b1a7-7a8030333de2|||33a3b23d-2143
sessionId=re.search(r'SESSION_ID=*|',line)
            if sessionId:
                print sessionId     
            else:
                print "Session id not found"
```

On executing this, i am getting the result as ,

**<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001EB8D98>**

But i need the result as **SESSION_ID=2a50250f-4a2e-4bf9-b1a7-7a8030333de2**.
Where i am going wrong?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is 'SESSION_ID=*|'. Character '|' should be escaped, and instead of `*` should be '.*'.

```
sessionId=re.search(r'SESSION_ID=.*\|',line)

if sessionId:
    print(sessionId.group())     
else:
    print("Session id not found")
```

Result is:

```
SESSION_ID=2a50250f-4a2e-4bf9-b1a7-7a8030333de2|||
```

Probably there are better ways of doing your search for this, but I just applied the simplest changes to your regexp.

Better way would be e.g.

```
sessionId=re.search(r'(SESSION_ID=[\w-]+)\|',line)

if sessionId:
    print(sessionId.group(1))     
else:
    print("Session id not found")
```

This gives:

```
SESSION_ID=2a50250f-4a2e-4bf9-b1a7-7a8030333de2
```

Comment: I used the above but unfortunately its not working for me.I am using Python 2.7 and i am getting
"Session id not found"

Comment: I just tested in 2.7.7. and seems to work. Do you have the same line as in your question? Maybe it does not work for other line?

Answer (score 0):

`search` captures in group:
replace :

```
print sessionId
```

to:

```
print sessionId.group()
```

demo:

```
>>> a = "hello how are you"
>>> k= re.search('[a-z]+',a)
>>> k
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f9c456fe030>
>>> k.group()
'hello'
```